# How to place a sticky bottom row/bar at ModalBottomSheet using jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, sticky-footer, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

When placing items within `ModalBottomSheet` they get stacked expanding the `Bottom sheet` till they reach a certain threshold of height, beyond which the user has to scroll the Bottom sheet up to load the overflowing content.

I'm trying to place a bottom row of composables like a `Button` and another rounded button, that's always fixed (whether the `ModalBottomSheet` is expanded or not).

What I've tried (using scaffold/column to wrap the whole bottom sheet content) always results in the bottom `row` being placed at the bottom, only at the expanded state.

That's that prototype that I'm aiming at

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can handle this via offset.
First, create a value to calculate the height of ModalBottomSheet:

```
var modalHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
```

After that, add this:

```
 ModalBottomSheet(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(0.dp)
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            modalHeight = it.size.height
        })
```

And then you can handle any element with offset
for example i have a LazyRow:

```
 LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .requiredHeight(170.dp)
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(
                        0,
                        (modalHeight - bottomSheetState.requireOffset() - footerHeight).toInt()
                    )
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 12.dp, end = 0.dp, start = 0.dp, bottom = 42.dp)
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    footerHeight = (((it.size.height * 1)) + bottomPadding + 0).toInt()
                }
                .shadow(4.dp, RoundedCornerShape(1.dp), spotColor = Color.Gray)
                .background(color = Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(1.dp))
            ,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
        )
```

You can use every element, like Text, Button and etc...

bottomPadding: I created this for space between the device buttons and my element.
footerHeight: this is the height of the element that you are using;  if the element is static, use the static value.

Comment: It raised the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The offset was read before being initialized. Did you access the offset in a phase before layout, like effects or composition?`. The only SO issue out there & issue tracker is concerned with material, but I'm using material3

Comment: I also use material 3 and I did not encounter this error.
This is my complete code. Maybe by checking it you can find your error clues:

https://github.com/mahdiasd/ComposeBottomDialogFilePicker/blob/master/BottomDialogFilePicker/src/main/java/mahdiasd/bottomdialogfilepicker/FilePickerDialog.kt

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by applying the bottom sheet offset to the button.

```
if (showBottomSheet) {
          ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = {
              showBottomSheet = false
            },
            sheetState = sheetState
          ) {
            // Sheet content
            Box(
              modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
              contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd
            ) {
              LazyColumn {
                items(50) {
                  Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "Hello $it"
                  )
                }
              }
              Button(modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .padding(20.dp)
                .offset {
                  IntOffset(
                    x = 0,
                    y = -sheetState.requireOffset().toInt()
                  )
                },
                onClick = {
                  scope.launch {
                    sheetState.hide()
                    showBottomSheet = false
                  }
                }) {
                Text(text = "Close")
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Notice that I used a Box container to put the button on top of the list. Then, I aligned the content of the Box to the bottom. When you drag the bottom sheet up, it doesn't change its size. It only changes the offset. So, I took that offset and simply moved the button up for the same amount.